# Reference on manifolds with boundary

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

I am here because I want to know if someone knows of some good e fast books or  references about manifolds with boundary. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Search in John Lee, Topological Manifolds or John Lee, Smooth manifolds. If you want something more analytic then I suggest Michael Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds.

Comment: You can also find a detailed and basic approach on Munkres Analysis on Manifolds, but this is quite detailed and can be boring.